# Live Streaming of Audio from one Android device to other using socket(TCP) and service

Tags: android, sockets, service, tcp, audio-streaming

I am trying to stream audio from server to client(FYI, Application acts both as server and client, so same app can communicate bi-directional) using socket with TCP. 
My application open a serverSocket in starting of the application on some port so it act as server. when server sends "Start" to client a Service get started on client and records the voice on clinet and send it back to server(Any of other devices can do the same since they both have ServerSocket Open and can behave as client as well). Here I need the live audio streaming b/w server and client.

I am able to receive start command, startservice on client. client is recording and I think sending back to server because on server it prints received inputStream. it prints some garbage value. When I try to convert received byte array to audio I am getting
**W/AudioTrack(8259): obtainBuffer() track 0xf3b00 disabled, restarting**  on server.

Here is the code I am using

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button pinger, sendFile;
private EditText otherIP, msg;
private TextView myIP, msgLog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pinger = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pingButton);
    sendFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendFile);
    otherIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otherIP);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgToServer);
    myIP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myIP);
    msgLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgToLog);

    pinger.setOnClickListener(this);
    sendFile.setOnClickListener(this);
    myIP.setText("My IPs \n" + Utils.getIPAddress(true));
    otherIP.setText(Utils.getIPAddress(true));

    new OpenServerThread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(pinger)) {
        new ControlCommands(this, otherIP.getText().toString(), 8080, msg
                .getText().toString(), "") {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                String s = msgLog.getText().toString().trim();
                msgLog.setText(s);
                msg.setText("");
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
 }
}
```

**OpenServerThread.java**

```
public class OpenServerThread extends Thread {

private Socket socket;
String msg;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Context context;
private TextView t;

public OpenServerThread(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    setPriority(1);
    t = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.msgToLog);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("opening socket...");
    DataInputStream din = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                t.setText("I'm waiting here: "
                        + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            // inputStream is the base class to read bytes from a stream
            // (network or file) as primitive Data type.
            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            int length = din.readInt(); // read length of incoming message
            if (length > 0) {
                byte[] message = new byte[length];
                din.readFully(message, 0, message.length);
                msg = new String(message);


               /**
                * Here after receiving messege I am trying to convert byte
                * array to audio and this is main area of concern 
                **/

                if (message.length == length && length >5 ) {
                    System.out.println("Message: " + message.length);
                    playMp3(message);

                }

            }

            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    t.setText(msg);
                }
            });

            // din.close();

            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (msg.equals("start")) {
                        context.startService(new Intent(context,
                                MyService.class));
                        System.out.println("rec starting");
                    } else if (msg.equals("stop")) {
                        System.out.println("rec Stoping");
                        context.stopService(new Intent(context,
                                MyService.class));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("some other msg");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 //This function is producing error I have mentioned above 
 private void playMp3(final byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) {
     int sampleRate = 44100;
     int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

     AudioTrack mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     mAudioTrack.write(mp3SoundByteArray, 0, mp3SoundByteArray.length);
     mAudioTrack.play();
 } 
}
```

**ControlCommands.java**

```
public class ControlCommands extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String dstAddress;
int dstPort;
String msgToServer;
String selectedFilePath;
Context context;

ControlCommands(Context context, String addr, int port, String msgTo,
        String selectedFilePath) {
    dstAddress = addr;
    dstPort = port;
    msgToServer = msgTo;
    this.selectedFilePath = selectedFilePath;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    System.out.println("dst add: " + dstAddress + " : " + dstPort
            + " msgttoser: " + msgToServer);
    Socket socket = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        if (selectedFilePath.equals("")) {
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            dataOutputStream.writeInt(msgToServer.getBytes().length);
            dataOutputStream.write(msgToServer.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 44100;
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig,
        audioFormat);
private boolean status = true;
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    Toast.makeText(this, "recard Started Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

public void startStreaming(String Ip) {
    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //IP is correct this is where I have to send the data
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.105", 8080); 

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                            socket.getOutputStream());

                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat,
                        minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                recorder.startRecording();

                while (status == true) {
                     buffer = new byte[minBufSize];
                    // reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(buffer.length); // write length of the message
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer);

                    //System.out.println(new String(buffer).substring(0,4));
                    dataOutputStream.flush();

                    status = false;
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    streamThread.start();
}

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
     recorder.stop();
     recorder.release();
     Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
     startStreaming("");
     Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your text a bit as what should happen is unclear to me. You have a server app and a client app. Please use the words server and client instead of -other- device.

Comment: Ok. But you will have a server and a client. Please rephrase using words `the server` and `the client`.

Comment: `when server sends "Start" to client a Service get started`. On server or client? Please tell exactly what is happening. Edit your post please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73328/discussion-between-ashutiwari4-and-greenapps).

Comment: `I am able to receive start command,` You mean: the client does receive the start command. `and I think sending back to server`. It will not send anything back i think. The client just sends the audio.

Comment: `When I try to convert received byte array`. To test your configuration you should first know if the bytes sent by the client are all received ok by the server. To check this you could let the client save all bytes to file too. Also you could let the server save all received bytes to file. Then later compare those two files.

Comment: I have print the length of buffer on client as wwell on server it is same
Buffer size on client is: 3776 
Buffer size on server is: 3776
Lets continue in chat I sent you request

Comment: What you told about server and client and who is doing what is not to the point. Your serverSocket receives a 'start' command and starts 'MyService' which does the audio and connects to another server. So where I assumed that your app can behave as a server OR a client it seems that both instances -on two devices- behave both as server and as client.

Comment: `minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
 dataOutputStream.writeInt(buffer.length); dataOutputStream.write(buffer);`. That cannot work. Better change to  `int nread = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(nread); dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, nread);`
 
 `

Comment: Your serverSocket receives a 'start' command and starts 'MyService' which does the audio, Service creates a socket and connects to another server. So basically the device which run the service behaves as client and which is not running behaves like server

Comment: Changing variable name is not problem. it's not working, this is the problem. Change which ever variable in what ever ways. You should understand. That's the thing

Comment: No. I did not change a variable name. You can keep `minBufSize` to declare the buffer. I introduced a new variable which you really need to check what is read and how much you can send. You are checking buffer sizes where you should check buffer content instead.

Comment: content are same, I checked that too. Yes of course go on, Introduce whatever you want :)

Comment: `status = false;` Why are you doing that? How many seconds would that recording be?

Comment: Which permissions does one need in manifest to try this out?

Comment: Status = false, I did for test purpose. It shouldn't be there. These are the permission I am using
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Ok. If status=false is removed then adapt  the while(true) block on receiving side. Take the first two code lines out. Place them before the while.

Comment: You should have there two while(true) loops. One for accepting new clients. And one for reading from the input stream. How many seconds go in one recording block? I asked that before.

Comment: the same while loop is doing both work by using a condition. what's problem in that

Comment: O and i forgot to say that you should not only take these two lines out but also make socket and din local variables there.